# 'ManyToOne' attribute type should not be 'Subcategory'

Tags: spring-boot

For nearly 2 days, I've been dealing with this issue. I've tried everything, from deleting the file to reinstalling IntelliJ. Do you have any idea how I could resolve this error?

OneToMany:

`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subcategory") private List<BaseProduct> baseProducts;`

ManyToOne:

[image]

I changed the class name.
I thought it was a grammar error. I deleted the file and recreated it. I tried to change the column and table names. I reinstalled IntelliJ.